# Network issue - client on Android device not connecting to server on my laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-router, firewall, android, port-forwarding

I have a server app running on my windows 7 laptop and I have a client app running on my Android phone.

Both, laptop and phone when connected to my work WIFI can communicate. I can log it into my client and fetch data from server.

However, on my home WIFI, I cannot do that.

I did some research and found an article suggesting to use Wireless Network Connection Properties, Sharing tab to enable Internet connection sharing but that option has been disabled on my machine, so I am looking for another way, if there is any.

Some have suggested to go to my home WiFi router settings and do port forwarding. I did some research on that and found that it is used if you want to allow access from a connection from outside your home network to a device on your home network. So, that doesn't apply to me as both of my devices are on my home WIFI.

Another recommendation was to go to my router settings and disable firewall. But that does not sound like a good idea to me.

Can anyone provide some nice article or instructions with explanations how to do it one or the other way ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check for WiFi isolation options on the router, if you find it, disable it.  Also, if you're using your external/WAN IP from inside the LAN to try and contact the server on your LAN, that probably won't work on your home-level router -- use the LAN IP.

Comment: I'll check the router for 'isolation option' but to other points, both device and laptiop are connected to my home WIFI and I am using my private IPs (ips within the home network), not the public ISP provided IP.  Thanks

Comment: No 'isolation option' in my router settings

Comment: If ICS is disabled, is this a work provided laptop?

Comment: yes, that is why I am wondering if there is other way to make it work only within my home network.  My IT guy said to disable router firewall but that just does not sound right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing, no answer to this question.  Anyways, I found it.
I went to my Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings and added incoming rule as:
Protocol Type: TCP
Local Port: my port #
Everything else was left as default
, and that worked.
Thanks